# How to draw a route on OSM on flutter App

Tags: flutter, routes, openstreetmap

I have create a component to display OpenStreetMap (OSM) on the view.

Question: How can I draw a static route on the map.

It should look like the following map I captured from GoogleMap.
[image]

What I have done so far. I created a view to show map.
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

class TrailMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TrailMapPageState createState() => _TrailMapPageState();
}

class _TrailMapPageState extends State<TrailMapPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("TrailMapPage")),
      body: _map(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _map(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(22.3193, 114.1694),
        zoom: 13.0,
      ),
      layers: [
        new TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        new MarkerLayerOptions(
          markers: [
            new Marker(
              width: 80.0,
              height: 80.0,
              point: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
              builder: (ctx) => new Container(
                child: new FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good question, have you had any progress yet? I have the idea of getting a gpx file in the form of a string and then adding the points to the map from the string.  Been searching for solutions for days and nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

You may check out the below Flutter Maps widget which has a polyline feature that allows adding routes on top of the map.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_maps

Check the below link for more details.

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/vector-layers/polyline-layer#adding-polylines

Comment: it's not at all free, they have license

Answer (score 0):

Look up project OSRM. It's free as far as I know.